# Why does my Octave script not display figures and msgbox s when I run it through powershell like: "octave myscript" but works in octave-cli?

Tags: powershell, octave

I have a long script that calculates a lot of things and displays a few figures and dialogue boxes. It runs as intended in octave-cli and the gui version, but when I write "octave myscript" in powershell it gets to the figures and then gives the following error messages:

Error: File C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.2.0\mingw64\share\octave\6.2.0\m\plot\util\private_*opengl_print*_.m
, Name C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.2.0\mingw64\share\octave\6.2.0\m\plot\util\print.m, Line 67, Column 58
Error: File \Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.2.0\mingw64\share\octave\6.2.0\m\plot\util\saveas.m
, Name {my directory}\OldAnalysis.m, Line 95, Column 95
Error: File opengl_print__
, Name print, Line 115, Column 97
Error: File veas
, Name OldAnalysis, Line 209, Column 757
Error: File s
, Name , Line 7, Column 16
Error: File
, Name , Line print: figure must be visible or qt toolkit must be used with **gl_window** property 'on' or QT_OFFSCREEN feature available
LoopTime = 39.694
error: 'Resultmessage' undefined near line 1749, column 1749
error: called from
OldAnalysis at line 1749 column 3

Also "Resultmessage" should be defined...
Super weird. Can't find anything online about this. Does anyone know why running octave through powershell like this is not the same as running octave-cli?

An alternative fix could be to have my powershell script open the app and send code to it, but it would be ugly, inefficient, and I frankly don't know how I'd go about doing that either.

Please help!

I tried to run the exact same script that worked perfectly in octave-cli through powershell and expected them to work the same. I thought powershell would simply run octave in the same way, but the results were different. See error messages.

I have checked pkg list to make sure that the packages are loaded in.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run ```octave myscript``` from a Windows Command Prompt (not PowerShell)? Or does that work?

Comment: For some reason Powershell is not compatible with Octave because Powershell behaves a bit different than the old Windows cmd. The octave-cli is compatible with the old Windows cmd.